# Doubts about keycloak for end-user

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

All my questions may sound fool, but I'm learning keycloak, and I have some questions about it.

Is it ok to have 2 realms, one for my backoffice(staff) and other for end-users(customers)?

the realm staff will only login using google federation (will only accept email of my company), and I will use the power of SSO in all software my company uses, this realm won't allow self-signup. (for this case it's OK)

in the other side, the realm customer (for end-user), the registration is open for everyone, they can use google and facebook, as well as plain password and e-mail. Also my platform have a native app (iOS and Android), and the customers will login/sign-up via API (native login and signup screen with textfields)

Does it make any sense to use keycloak for customers?

Thanks